# SSH connection with python

Tags: python, ssh

I'd like to make a python script that connect with an SSH server, but as I can't send password as an `argv`, how could I do that?

```
os.system("user@server password")
```

And if it fails, what would be the return?

Comment: what do you want to do after connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Paramiko:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect('my.example.com', username='brandon', password=mypass)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably looking into doing this with a library or wrapper to make this work out properly and with more support. Here are some [examples](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell).

Answer (score 2):

You can use some 3rd libraries like [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/) or [Paramiko](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/)